# What does "しぇんぱい" mean?

Tags: words, hiragana

Does "しぇんぱい" mean someone, who seems to be having a grudge. Or does it mean some who seems to be rehearsing?

I made this assumption since the only words that appear in my dictionary that has the word "しぇん" and one that might fit to the scenario of what I'm reading is "私怨" and "試演".

There are also other "しぇん" words like: "支援" "紫煙".

But which among these 4 Japanese words are commonly written in hiragana and connected with "~ぱい"?

Comment: Is there any more context? What comes to my mind from しぇんぱい is mispronounced way of saying 先輩 because しぇ with small え is pronounced "she"

Comment: Thank you. I think your right. I'm sorry I didn't write more context. It's because I thought it was unnecessary in this case. I thought it was simply a word connected to the suffix "~ぱい". The scenario, where I read this word, is a 後輩 with a fever talking to her 先輩.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably a slurred 先輩【せんぱい】. Since there is no context, I am only 95% certain. 先輩 is commonly used to address your senior at school or at work when there is no other appropriate title like 部長. Maybe someone, typically a young school girl, said it in a fawning way.

Answer (score 5):

I think that しぇんぱい *shempai* is used by mannerless guys with friendly feeling in substitution for 先輩｛せんぱい｝.
This kind of slur is also used like しぇんしぇー *shensheh* for 先生｛せんせい｝ by them.

Apart from the scenario, さしすせそ is often pronounced like *sa shi su **she** so* in the North Kyushu rigion by elders.
The famous singer Tetsuya Takeda is from Fukuoka prefecture in the North Kyushu region. He sings like しぇんしぇい in stead of 先生｛せんせい｝ in his song.　He would pronounce the word 先輩 like しぇんぱい.